# Newman Postman test results in Azure do not show test names

Tags: postman-collection-runner

Following the instructions on [this Medium post](https://medium.com/@ganeshsirsi/how-to-configure-postman-newman-api-tests-in-azure-devops-or-tfs-and-publish-html-results-caf60a25c8b9) I have my Postman tests running under [newman](https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman) however when the report is published the `Test Case Title` is simply `Status code is 200`.

I have set a name and description for each test in the collection but still they are indistinguishable from each other in the test report.

How can I set `newman` to generate a report with the actual test names (or descriptions) as the `Test Case Titles`?

Comment: That would be the name of the test `Status code is 200` - Unless you have called it something else in the `pm.test()` function? Are you talking about the request name and not the test name?

Comment: Yes, I have this in the test tab: pm.test("Status code is 200", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
}); D'oh!

Comment: Shameless plug but if you wanted a different Newman reporting option....https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman-reporter-htmlextra

Comment: Saw that :) But only need it integrated into Azure - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script in my `Postman` "Test" tab was reporting an explicit test name, so I changed it to match the request name in the collection:

```
pm.test("Status code is 200", function () { pm.response.to.have.status(200); });
```

To this:

```
pm.test("Request name being tested", function () { pm.response.to.have.status(200); });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Export you Postman collection json and environment json
2. Install Newman using NPM package installer
3. To execute the collection using Newman cli from the documentation ["Command line integration with Newman"](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/collection-runs/command-line-integration-with-newman/)
4. **Now the answer to your question is** 
   you can follow my article from LinkedIn ["Postman test reporting using htmlextra"](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/postman-test-reporting-using-htmlextra-manish-tiwari/)
5. After that an html file will be generated and you can have this file as html report which can be shared via email as well.